# Java to Oracle connection issue

Tags: java, oracle

I'm using the below code to connect oracle 10g and retrieve some data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{  
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl","scott","tiger");  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
        while(rs.next())  
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
        con.close();  

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        System.out.println(e);
    }     
}
```

It works fine some time, But some time it throws below error and not connecting :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

The Connection descriptor used by the client was:

127.0.0.1:1521/orcl
```

Comment: are you using oracle 9i? ORA-12518 has been known to occur in Oracle Net Services version 9.2.0.5-10.2.0.1 in which attempting new connections on the database throw either ORA-12518 or TNS-12518.  ORA-12518 appears in the listener log upon new user connection.

Comment: I suggest you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624464/ora-12518-tnslistener-could-not-hand-off-client-connection

Comment: Although I highly doubt this is the reason: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` has been deprecated for ages, you should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`. Also which JDBC driver version are you using? You can check that using `con.getMetaData().getDriverVersion()`

Answer (score 0):

try setting

> DIRECT_HANDOFF_TTC_LISTENER=OFF

you will find this file unde $oraclehome/product/$version/server/listners.ora

sometimes this may also occur due to limited resources. before you do anything try restarting oracle, after doing this, if the problem dissapears, it means is a limited resources error.

Answer (score 0):

Given the intermittent behaviour, you may have some server issue or reached a limit. Check the listener.log and alert.log to see if there is another underlying Oracle error that is preventing a session from being created.

My guess is that you have too many sessions or process. Count the number of rows on  the  v$session and  v$process views and compare to the database parameters "sessions" and "processes". You may have to increase them. Also, check if your application is not leaving unused sessions behind, otherwise you will run out of sessions no matter how high you set the parameters.