# ORA-12518 TNS:listener could not hand off client connection in data source from JBOSS 6,X

Tags: jdbc, datasource, oracle12c, jboss6.x

I am using ORACLE 12c database  in our Application while starting Applications 
showing below error.

**WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 )**

Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for FooDB; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for FooDB)

Here is My connections URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mydomain.com)(PORT=1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=SHARED)(SERVICE_NAME=FOODB)(FAILOVER_MODE=(.......
```

this unknown issue leads application performance issue while longing into app looking for any parameters to add from jboss as database is in 2 node clustered environment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624464/ora-12518-tnslistener-could-not-hand-off-client-connection)