# Connected To XEPDB1 From SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

Totally a newbie to Oracle, and have spent over three whole days on this without any luck.

I need to do something within a PDB, and I noticed that one was created by default right after the installation (Express edition), it's connection URL is:

localhost:1521/XEPDB1

All I want is to connect to this PDB from my SQL Developer, and so that I can do my stuff.

After reading some blogs and watching some videos, I have modified some config files. My tnsnames.ora now reads like:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Android-Studio.hub)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Android-Studio.hub)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Android-Studio.hub)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

My listener.ora reads like:

```
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Vincent\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Vincent\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_NAME = XEPDB1)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Vincent\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (SID_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Android-Studio.hub)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Below is what I see after restarting the listener:

[image]

The error I see is:

[image]

I am running out of options, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same question with some answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624464/ora-12518-tnslistener-could-not-hand-off-client-connection

Comment: Thanks Kris. I have managed to solve it by changing the values of parameter processes (from 640 to 800) and large_pool_size (from 0 to 500m). I also found that it still works after reverting the changes, I rebooted afterward to make sure the changes would be applied. I still don't know why it didn't work previously as I don't know why it works now.

Comment: you shouldn't have had to make any changes to the tns/sqlnet ora or init config items to run the 18c XE image and connect to the PDB from SQLDev...did you make any other changes after download/install?

Comment: I did not. When I tried to connect to XEPDB1, I received errors, one of them is something like the service name is not recognized or resolved, so I googled and changed tnsname file, and then I got an error about listener. I tried that on Windows 7.